# How do I use Dialog Config in Mozilla mobile components?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using [this](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/reference-browser) project as a base for my app and I having trouble to pre-select the remember decision checkbox then the website asking for permissions.

I found this [URL](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/blob/master/docs/api/mozilla.components.feature.sitepermissions/-site-permissions-feature/-dialog-config/index.md) that shows:

```
Constructors
Name    Summary
<init>  DialogConfig(shouldPreselectDoNotAskAgain: Boolean = false)
Customization options for feature request dialog

Properties
Name    Summary
shouldPreselectDoNotAskAgain    val shouldPreselectDoNotAskAgain: Boolean
Use true to pre-select "Do not ask again" checkbox.
```

But I don't know how to implant that (I am a n00b)
My code for getting the permission:

```
sitePermissionFeature.set(
        feature = SitePermissionsFeature(
            context = requireContext(),
            fragmentManager = requireFragmentManager(),
            sessionManager = requireComponents.core.sessionManager,
            sessionId = sessionId
        ) { permissions ->
            requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CODE_APP_PERMISSIONS)
        },
        owner = this,
        view = view
    )
```

I wanted to edit the sitePermissionFeature.kt file but it's not edible file..

That is the last thing I need on my project, so if anyone can please help me find a solution it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DialogConfig](https://mozac.org/api/mozilla.components.feature.sitepermissions/-site-permissions-feature/-dialog-config/) is an optional parameter of the constructor of [SitePermissionsFeature](https://mozac.org/api/mozilla.components.feature.sitepermissions/-site-permissions-feature/). Using [Reference Browser](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/reference-browser/), you can add it inside [BaseBrowserFragment](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/reference-browser/blob/73d70a8b50ce10c9981d4868bd293be7169ab2d2/app/src/main/java/org/mozilla/reference/browser/browser/BaseBrowserFragment.kt#L182) like this:

```
sitePermissionFeature.set(
    feature = SitePermissionsFeature(
        context = requireContext(),
        fragmentManager = requireFragmentManager(),
        sessionManager = requireComponents.core.sessionManager,
        sessionId = sessionId,
        dialogConfig = SitePermissionsFeature.DialogConfig(
            shouldPreselectDoNotAskAgain = true
        )
    ) { permissions ->
        requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CODE_APP_PERMISSIONS)
    },
    owner = this,
    view = view
)
```

Comment: Thank you for that!